# extract info from another web page

Tags: php

I have this test.php where i have this info :

```
callername1 : 'Fernando Verdasco1'
callername2 : 'Fernando Verdasco2'
callername3 : 'Fernando Verdasco3'
callername4 : 'Fernando Verdasco4'
callername5 : 'Fernando Verdasco5'
```

this page automatically changes that  name every 10 min

In this another page test1.php

I need a php code that takes only the name of the callername3 and echo'it

```
Fernando Verdasco3
```

I've tried this like so test1.php?id=callername3

```
<?php 
  $Text=file_get_contents("test.php");
  if(isset($_GET["id"])){
     $id = $_GET["id"];
     parse_str($Text,$data);
     echo $data[$id];
  } else {
     echo "";
  }

?>
```

but no result.

Is there any other option?

If i have "=" instade of ":"

```
callername1 = 'Fernando Verdasco1'
callername2 = 'Fernando Verdasco2'
callername3 = 'Fernando Verdasco3'
callername4 = 'Fernando Verdasco4'
callername5 = 'Fernando Verdasco5'
```

And i use This php Code it works

```
<?php 
    $Text=file_get_contents("test.php")
    ;preg_match_all('/callername3=\'([^\']+)\'/',$Text,$Match); 
    $fid=$Match[1][0]; 
    echo $fid;
```

?>

i need this to work with ":"

Help?

Comment: I hope `callername1 : 'Fernando Verdasco1'` isn't PHP because that is incorrect. And what is `$data`?

Comment: AFAIR parse_str only works with query string type format, you need a custom function to parse this.

Comment: @putvande, I could be the output of the PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store data in a file with the `.php` extension, since it's not executable PHP. I looks like you're going for the JSON syntax.

Since you need it to work with ':' I assume, for whatever reason, you can't change the format.  Your example with '=' works because of the regexp:

```
preg_match_all('/callername3=\'([^\']+)\'/',$Text,$Match);
```

This says, match text like `callername3=` followed by a `'` followed by one or more chars that are not a `'` followed by a final `'`. Everything between the `'`s is stored in $Match[1][0] (if there were more parts in brackets they be stored in $Match[2][0], etc).

Your example doesn't work since it doesn't account for the spaces before and after the `=` sign. But we can fix that up and change it to work for `:` like this:

```
preg_match('/callername3\s*:\s*\'([^\']+)\'/',$Text,$Match); 
echo $Match[1] ."\n";
```

This displays:

```
Fernando Verdasco3
```

And what that regular expression is match text that start `callername3` followed by any amount of whitespace (that's the `\s*`) followed by a `:`, followed by any amount of whitespace, followed by a name in quotes (that is stored in $Match[1], this is the area of the regular expression enclosed in parenthesis).

I've also used just `preg_match` because it looks like you only need to match one example.

Comment: thats ok but what if the info is like this 'callername3':'Fernando Verdasco3' how i resolve this?

Comment: If your input is like that you're very close to JSON syntax and you should look at json_decode in PHP (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). However, you can change the regexp just to add the quotes: `/\'callername3\'\s*:\s*\'([^\']+)\'/` or, if the quotes are optional `/\'?callername3\'?\s*:\s*\'([^\']+)\'/`

Answer (score 0):

There is a rather simple approach to tihs:

```
$fData = file_get_contents("test.php");
$lines = explode("\n", $fData);
foreach($lines as $line) {
    $t = explode(":", $line);

    echo trim($t[1]); // This will give you the name
}
```